# Memory error - Hierarchical Dirichlet Process, HDP gensim

Tags: python, nlp, topic-model, lda, gensim

I am running Hierarchical Dirichlet Process, HDP using gensim in Python but as my corpus is too large it is throwing me following error:

```
model = gensim.models.HdpModel(corpus, id2word=corpus.id2word, chunksize=50000)



 File "/usr/cluster/contrib/Enthought/Canopy_64/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/hdpmodel.py", line 210, in __init__
    self.update(corpus)
  File "/usr/cluster/contrib/Enthought/Canopy_64/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/hdpmodel.py", line 245, in update
    self.update_chunk(chunk)
  File "/usr/cluster/contrib/Enthought/Canopy_64/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/hdpmodel.py", line 313, in update_chunk
    self.update_lambda(ss, word_list, opt_o)
  File "/usr/cluster/contrib/Enthought/Canopy_64/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/hdpmodel.py", line 415, in update_lambda
    rhot * self.m_D * sstats.m_var_beta_ss / sstats.m_chunksize
MemoryError
```

I have loaded my corpus using following statement:

```
corpus = gensim.corpora.MalletCorpus('chunk5000K_records.mallet')
```

And the data which I used to load corpus has 5 million records. And this is working for me when I am loading only 50K records. So I have added chunksize option HdpModel but it is still giving me an error.

Please let me know how I can solve this issue. And I am running this on High Performance Computing so I think there should be a solution to resolve this issue as this cluster has really big size memory and disk capacity.

Answer (score 1):

you can use an alternative of HDP that is LDA. HDP won't give hierarchical output. HDP and LDA are both creating a flat hierarchy. The only difference is that HDP is generating topics based on topic generated in a pervious iteration. Online LDA is quite memory efficient as well as good at capturing topics.

Comment: My understanding is that NN's have gone a fair distance towards replcing LDA, did you find that as well?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to Python 3.x if at all possible. It is much more memory efficient than Python 2.7.

Additionally, genism has a guide to improving code performance. It is called [Distributed Computing](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/distributed.html) but has a section on improving single node performance. One suggestion is to make sure a fast BLAS (Basic Linear Algebra) library for NumPy is correctly installed and used.